# 2 Questions / 1. Fullscreen(jQuery) / 2. Background change and save as Cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, background, fullscreen

**Hello**,

i searched around the web, but can't find right peace of codes..

I want to do:
- go to Fullscreen mode on a button click.
- change a background color to dark and save it as cookies.

**Fullscreen mode**:

i'm new with jQuery and can't find a right code. I found one, but when i click on button to next page, it turn's off the full screen mode to normal browser window, and changes my website background colors.

Founded code:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="#" title="Go Fullscreen" onclick="toggleFullScreen()"><img src="fullscreen.png"></a>

    <script>
    function toggleFullScreen() {
      if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||    
      (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
      if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {  
          document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();  
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {  
          document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();  
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {  
          document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);  
        }  
        } else {  
        if (document.cancelFullScreen) {  
        document.cancelFullScreen();  
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {  
         document.mozCancelFullScreen();  
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {  
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();  
        }  
      }   
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Change Background and save as Cookies**:

I want to do, that a members chooses on radio button's a theme White or Dark. The White theme default `<div>` background is white #fff(White). When member chooses the Dark theme, it changes `<div>` background to #000000(Black) color. I'm new and can't write a code, without examples or something. Can someone tell me, how can i do it with Cookies and Javascript/jQuery?

**Members settings page to change it**:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Settings</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Change Theme</p>
    <form>
      <input type="radio" id="Light" title="White Theme">
      <br />
      <input type="radio" id="Dark" title="Dark theme">
      <br />
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Page **BEFORE** changes the Theme to Dark:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background:#fff;height:600px;width:100%;">
  <!-- SOME CONTENT -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and Page **AFTER** changes the Theme to Dark:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background:#000000;height:600px;width:100%;">
  <!-- SOME CONTENT -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Thanks!*

Comment: Kindly divide the post in two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a cookie value, like this:

```
document.cookie = "theme=black";
```

Or, if you want to keep other settings, then:

```
function changeCookieValue(attribute, value) {
    var previousCookie = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < previousCookie.length; i++) {
        var key = previousCookie[i].substring(0,previousCookie[i].indexOf("="));
        if (key === attribute) {
            previousCookie[i] = attribute + "=" + value;
            document.cookie = previousCookie.join(";");
            return;
        }
    }
    document.cookie = document.cookie + ";" + attribute + "=" + value;
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
`changeCookieValue("black");`
```

This is how you can read from cookie:

```
function getCookieValue(attribute) {
    var previousCookie = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < previousCookie.length; i++) {
        var key = previousCookie[i].substring(0,previousCookie[i].indexOf("="));
        if (key === attribute) {
            return presiousCookie[i].substring(previousCookie[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

You can set the class of the body, like this:

```
$("body").addClass(getCookieValue("theme"));
```

just make sure that body is already loaded when you run this part. You can design the themes like this:

```
.black > div {
    background: #000000;
}

.white > div {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Alternatively, you can work with [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), which is much more handy. As about full screen mode, there is no reason to reinvent the wheel, since there is a good [fullscreen API](http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/) you should use for this purpose.

And you can make sure that `changeCookieValue` runs with the proper parameter on click using the `onclick` attribute of your `radio` buttons.

Alternatively, you might consider storing the values inside a database and adding the needed class to body on server, when you generate it.

EDIT:

You can add the class at the loaded event:

```
$(function() {
    $("body").addClass(getCookieValue("theme"));
});
```

Note, that this will be responsible to display the theme at page load. You need to display it whenever you call `changeCookieValue` for theme. Before you call that `function` `$("body").removeClass(getCookieValue("theme"));` and after the `function` is executed `$("body").addClass(getCookieValue("theme"));` (note, that the theme is changed). Naturally, you need a wrapper for this:

```
function changeTheme(theme) {
    $("body").removeClass(getCookieValue("theme"));
    changeCookieValue("theme", theme);
    $("body").addClass(getCookieValue("theme"));
}
```

and trigger this `changeTheme` at your `radio` buttons.

Comment: Thank You!
 Can you maybe say, where should i put this code "$("body").addClass(getCookieValue("theme"));"? I Tried before return ""; at function getCookieValue(attribute) {

Comment: @o'Bass, you are welcome. I have added further details to my answer. You should not do it at getCookieValue, since you will not necessary call getCookieValue when you load the page or you set a cookie value.